# GUnload() a single Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got some Javascript/HTML code which displays a variable number of maps dependent on what the user selects.

I've worked how to dynamically create multiple maps on a page - that's well documented.

However, what I'm not so sure on is... how can I safely destroy a map after it's been created - normally I just leave this to GUnload() to sort out.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the Google Maps API does not yet provide a documented method to `GUnload()` a single map.

There is an open [Issue #772](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=772) for this feature on the Google Maps API Issue Tracker. On May 24 2009 it was marked as Acknowledged, but it remains open to this day.

In the [first comment](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=772#c1) of that issue, a Google Maps team member confirmed that a possible "partial" workaround at the moment is to call:

```
map_to_delete.clearOverlays();
GEvent.clearInstanceListeners(map_to_delete);
```

Comment: Still relevant in Google Maps v3, with the following changes: iterate map_to_delete.controls to call clear() method on any defined control, then call google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(map_to_delete)